# Get Administrotor Object in windows in different language

Tags: vbscript, locale

I've a vbscript to authenticate an user credentials, one part of my code is

```
  Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://./Administrators, group")
```

now this code fail in Windows(German and French Version), after debugging, I think the problem is that, in German Version, the Group corresponding to English "Administrators" was named "Administratoren"..

Is there any generic way to get the Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The administrators group has a [well-known SID](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330), so something like this should work:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set admins = wmi.Get("Win32_SID.SID='S-1-5-32-544'")
Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://./" & admins.AccountName & ",group")
```

[Another way](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/11/02/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-the-local-administrators-group.aspx) would be getting the name from the `Win32_Group` class:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Group WHERE SID = 'S-1-5-32-544'"
For Each group In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://./" & group.Name & ",group")
Next
```